# gnuplot pm3d map second column as color gradient

Tags: gnuplot

My data file : first column = x; second column = temperature; third = time

```
-4.975 0 0
-4.925 0 0
-4.875 0 0
-4.825 0 0
-4.775 0 0
-4.725 0 0
-4.675 0 0
-4.625 0 0
-4.575 0 0
-4.525 0 0
-4.475 0 0
-4.425 0 0
-4.375 0 0
-4.325 0 0
-4.275 0 0
-4.225 0 0
-4.175 0 0
-4.125 0 0
-4.075 0 0
-4.025 0 0
-3.975 0 0
-3.925 0 0
-3.875 0 0
-3.825 0 0
-3.775 0 0
-3.725 0 0
-3.675 0 0
-3.625 0 0
-3.575 0 0
-3.525 0 0
-3.475 0 0
-3.425 0 0
-3.375 0 0
-3.325 0 0
-3.275 0 0
-3.225 0 0
-3.175 0 0
-3.125 0 0
-3.075 0 0
-3.025 0 0
-2.975 0 0
-2.925 0 0
-2.875 0 0
-2.825 0 0
-2.775 0 0
-2.725 0 0
-2.675 0 0
-2.625 0 0
-2.575 0 0
-2.525 0 0
-2.475 0 0
-2.425 0 0
-2.375 0 0
-2.325 0 0
-2.275 0 0
-2.225 0 0
-2.175 0 0
-2.125 0 0
-2.075 0 0
-2.025 0 0
-1.975 0 0
-1.925 0 0
-1.875 0 0
-1.825 0 0
-1.775 0 0
-1.725 0 0
-1.675 0 0
-1.625 0 0
-1.575 0 0
-1.525 0 0
-1.475 0 0
-1.425 0 0
-1.375 0 0
-1.325 0 0
-1.275 0 0
-1.225 0 0
-1.175 0 0
-1.125 0 0
-1.075 0 0
-1.025 0 0
-0.975 0 0
-0.925 0 0
-0.875 0 0
-0.825 0 0
-0.775 0 0
-0.725 0 0
-0.675 0 0
-0.625 0 0
-0.575 0 0
-0.525 0 0
-0.475 0 0
-0.425 0 0
-0.375 0 0
-0.325 0 0
-0.275 0 0
-0.225 0 0
-0.175 0 0
-0.125 0 0
-0.075 5 0
-0.025 5 0
0.025 5 0
0.075 5 0
0.125 0 0
0.175 0 0
0.225 0 0
0.275 0 0
0.325 0 0
0.375 0 0
0.425 0 0
0.475 0 0
0.525 0 0
0.575 0 0
0.625 0 0
0.675 0 0
0.725 0 0
0.775 0 0
0.825 0 0
0.875 0 0
0.925 0 0
0.975 0 0
1.025 0 0
1.075 0 0
1.125 0 0
1.175 0 0
1.225 0 0
1.275 0 0
1.325 0 0
1.375 0 0
1.425 0 0
1.475 0 0
1.525 0 0
1.575 0 0
1.625 0 0
1.675 0 0
1.725 0 0
1.775 0 0
1.825 0 0
1.875 0 0
1.925 0 0
1.975 0 0
2.025 0 0
2.075 0 0
2.125 0 0
2.175 0 0
2.225 0 0
2.275 0 0
2.325 0 0
2.375 0 0
2.425 0 0
2.475 0 0
2.525 0 0
2.575 0 0
2.625 0 0
2.675 0 0
2.725 0 0
2.775 0 0
2.825 0 0
2.875 0 0
2.925 0 0
2.975 0 0
3.025 0 0
3.075 0 0
3.125 0 0
3.175 0 0
3.225 0 0
3.275 0 0
3.325 0 0
3.375 0 0
3.425 0 0
3.475 0 0
3.525 0 0
3.575 0 0
3.625 0 0
3.675 0 0
3.725 0 0
3.775 0 0
3.825 0 0
3.875 0 0
3.925 0 0
3.975 0 0
4.025 0 0
4.075 0 0
4.125 0 0
4.175 0 0
4.225 0 0
4.275 0 0
4.325 0 0
4.375 0 0
4.425 0 0
4.475 0 0
4.525 0 0
4.575 0 0
4.625 0 0
4.675 0 0
4.725 0 0
4.775 0 0
4.825 0 0
4.875 0 0
4.925 0 0
4.975 0 0


-4.975 0 0.1
-4.925 0 0.1
-4.875 0 0.1
-4.825 0 0.1
-4.775 0 0.1
-4.725 0 0.1
-4.675 0 0.1
-4.625 0 0.1
-4.575 0 0.1
-4.525 0 0.1
-4.475 0 0.1
-4.425 0 0.1
-4.375 0 0.1
-4.325 0 0.1
-4.275 0 0.1
-4.225 0 0.1
-4.175 0 0.1
-4.125 0 0.1
-4.075 4.1359e-24 0.1
-4.025 4.1359e-24 0.1
-3.975 3.35008e-22 0.1
-3.925 3.35008e-22 0.1
-3.875 1.34003e-20 0.1
-3.825 1.34003e-20 0.1
-3.775 3.52875e-19 0.1
-3.725 3.52875e-19 0.1
-3.675 6.88107e-18 0.1
-3.625 6.88107e-18 0.1
-3.575 1.05968e-16 0.1
-3.525 1.05968e-16 0.1
-3.475 1.34227e-15 0.1
-3.425 1.34227e-15 0.1
-3.375 1.43814e-14 0.1
-3.325 1.43814e-14 0.1
-3.275 1.33028e-13 0.1
-3.225 1.33028e-13 0.1
-3.175 1.07901e-12 0.1
-3.125 1.07901e-12 0.1
-3.075 7.76885e-12 0.1
-3.025 7.76885e-12 0.1
-2.975 5.01444e-11 0.1
-2.925 5.01444e-11 0.1
-2.875 2.92509e-10 0.1
-2.825 2.92509e-10 0.1
-2.775 1.55255e-09 0.1
-2.725 1.55255e-09 0.1
-2.675 7.54094e-09 0.1
-2.625 7.54094e-09 0.1
-2.575 3.36829e-08 0.1
-2.525 3.36829e-08 0.1
-2.475 1.38942e-07 0.1
-2.425 1.38942e-07 0.1
-2.375 5.31248e-07 0.1
-2.325 5.31248e-07 0.1
-2.275 1.88888e-06 0.1
-2.225 1.88888e-06 0.1
-2.175 6.26314e-06 0.1
-2.125 6.26314e-06 0.1
-2.075 1.94157e-05 0.1
-2.025 1.94157e-05 0.1
-1.975 5.63981e-05 0.1
-1.925 5.63981e-05 0.1
-1.875 0.000153813 0.1
-1.825 0.000153813 0.1
-1.775 0.000394564 0.1
-1.725 0.000394564 0.1
-1.675 0.000953529 0.1
-1.625 0.000953529 0.1
-1.575 0.00217405 0.1
-1.525 0.00217405 0.1
-1.475 0.00468256 0.1
-1.425 0.00468256 0.1
-1.375 0.00953855 0.1
-1.325 0.00953855 0.1
-1.275 0.0183958 0.1
-1.225 0.0183958 0.1
-1.175 0.0336199 0.1
-1.125 0.0336199 0.1
-1.075 0.0582744 0.1
-1.025 0.0582744 0.1
-0.975 0.0958708 0.1
-0.925 0.0958708 0.1
-0.875 0.149798 0.1
-0.825 0.149798 0.1
-0.775 0.222428 0.1
-0.725 0.222428 0.1
-0.675 0.314015 0.1
-0.625 0.314015 0.1
-0.575 0.421678 0.1
-0.525 0.421678 0.1
-0.475 0.538811 0.1
-0.425 0.538811 0.1
-0.375 0.65531 0.1
-0.325 0.65531 0.1
-0.275 0.75878 0.1
-0.225 0.75878 0.1
-0.175 0.836604 0.1
-0.125 0.836604 0.1
-0.075 0.878434 0.1
-0.025 0.878434 0.1
0.025 0.878434 0.1
0.075 0.878434 0.1
0.125 0.836604 0.1
0.175 0.836604 0.1
0.225 0.75878 0.1
0.275 0.75878 0.1
0.325 0.65531 0.1
0.375 0.65531 0.1
0.425 0.538811 0.1
0.475 0.538811 0.1
0.525 0.421678 0.1
0.575 0.421678 0.1
0.625 0.314015 0.1
0.675 0.314015 0.1
0.725 0.222428 0.1
0.775 0.222428 0.1
0.825 0.149798 0.1
0.875 0.149798 0.1
0.925 0.0958708 0.1
0.975 0.0958708 0.1
1.025 0.0582744 0.1
1.075 0.0582744 0.1
1.125 0.0336199 0.1
1.175 0.0336199 0.1
1.225 0.0183958 0.1
1.275 0.0183958 0.1
1.325 0.00953855 0.1
1.375 0.00953855 0.1
1.425 0.00468256 0.1
1.475 0.00468256 0.1
1.525 0.00217405 0.1
1.575 0.00217405 0.1
1.625 0.000953529 0.1
1.675 0.000953529 0.1
1.725 0.000394564 0.1
1.775 0.000394564 0.1
1.825 0.000153813 0.1
1.875 0.000153813 0.1
1.925 5.63981e-05 0.1
1.975 5.63981e-05 0.1
2.025 1.94157e-05 0.1
2.075 1.94157e-05 0.1
2.125 6.26314e-06 0.1
2.175 6.26314e-06 0.1
2.225 1.88888e-06 0.1
2.275 1.88888e-06 0.1
2.325 5.31248e-07 0.1
2.375 5.31248e-07 0.1
2.425 1.38942e-07 0.1
2.475 1.38942e-07 0.1
2.525 3.36829e-08 0.1
2.575 3.36829e-08 0.1
2.625 7.54094e-09 0.1
2.675 7.54094e-09 0.1
2.725 1.55255e-09 0.1
2.775 1.55255e-09 0.1
2.825 2.92509e-10 0.1
2.875 2.92509e-10 0.1
2.925 5.01444e-11 0.1
2.975 5.01444e-11 0.1
3.025 7.76885e-12 0.1
3.075 7.76885e-12 0.1
3.125 1.07901e-12 0.1
3.175 1.07901e-12 0.1
3.225 1.33028e-13 0.1
3.275 1.33028e-13 0.1
3.325 1.43814e-14 0.1
3.375 1.43814e-14 0.1
3.425 1.34227e-15 0.1
3.475 1.34227e-15 0.1
3.525 1.05968e-16 0.1
3.575 1.05968e-16 0.1
3.625 6.88107e-18 0.1
3.675 6.88107e-18 0.1
3.725 3.52875e-19 0.1
3.775 3.52875e-19 0.1
3.825 1.34003e-20 0.1
3.875 1.34003e-20 0.1
3.925 3.35008e-22 0.1
3.975 3.35008e-22 0.1
4.025 4.1359e-24 0.1
4.075 4.1359e-24 0.1
4.125 0 0.1
4.175 0 0.1
4.225 0 0.1
4.275 0 0.1
4.325 0 0.1
4.375 0 0.1
4.425 0 0.1
4.475 0 0.1
4.525 0 0.1
4.575 0 0.1
4.625 0 0.1
4.675 0 0.1
4.725 0 0.1
4.775 0 0.1
4.825 0 0.1
4.875 0 0.1
4.925 0 0.1
4.975 0 0.1


-4.975 6.03923e-15 0.2
-4.925 6.03923e-15 0.2
-4.875 2.01022e-14 0.2
-4.825 2.01022e-14 0.2
-4.775 7.76118e-14 0.2
-4.725 7.76118e-14 0.2
-4.675 2.91982e-13 0.2
-4.625 2.91982e-13 0.2
-4.575 1.05944e-12 0.2
-4.525 1.05944e-12 0.2
-4.475 3.70802e-12 0.2
-4.425 3.70802e-12 0.2
-4.375 1.25271e-11 0.2
-4.325 1.25271e-11 0.2
-4.275 4.08779e-11 0.2
-4.225 4.08779e-11 0.2
-4.175 1.28922e-10 0.2
-4.125 1.28922e-10 0.2
-4.075 3.93214e-10 0.2
-4.025 3.93214e-10 0.2
-3.975 1.16046e-09 0.2
-3.925 1.16046e-09 0.2
-3.875 3.3156e-09 0.2
-3.825 3.3156e-09 0.2
-3.775 9.17573e-09 0.2
-3.725 9.17573e-09 0.2
-3.675 2.46076e-08 0.2
-3.625 2.46076e-08 0.2
-3.575 6.39798e-08 0.2
-3.525 6.39798e-08 0.2
-3.475 1.6134e-07 0.2
-3.425 1.6134e-07 0.2
-3.375 3.94769e-07 0.2
-3.325 3.94769e-07 0.2
-3.275 9.37577e-07 0.2
-3.225 9.37577e-07 0.2
-3.175 2.16217e-06 0.2
-3.125 2.16217e-06 0.2
-3.075 4.84325e-06 0.2
-3.025 4.84325e-06 0.2
-2.975 1.05412e-05 0.2
-2.925 1.05412e-05 0.2
-2.875 2.22987e-05 0.2
-2.825 2.22987e-05 0.2
-2.775 4.58596e-05 0.2
-2.725 4.58596e-05 0.2
-2.675 9.17192e-05 0.2
-2.625 9.17192e-05 0.2
-2.575 0.000178435 0.2
-2.525 0.000178435 0.2
-2.475 0.000337753 0.2
-2.425 0.000337753 0.2
-2.375 0.000622176 0.2
-2.325 0.000622176 0.2
-2.275 0.00111563 0.2
-2.225 0.00111563 0.2
-2.175 0.00194762 0.2
-2.125 0.00194762 0.2
-2.075 0.00331095 0.2
-2.025 0.00331095 0.2
-1.975 0.00548207 0.2
-1.925 0.00548207 0.2
-1.875 0.00884205 0.2
-1.825 0.00884205 0.2
-1.775 0.0138946 0.2
-1.725 0.0138946 0.2
-1.675 0.0212762 0.2
-1.625 0.0212762 0.2
-1.575 0.0317506 0.2
-1.525 0.0317506 0.2
-1.475 0.0461827 0.2
-1.425 0.0461827 0.2
-1.375 0.0654829 0.2
-1.325 0.0654829 0.2
-1.275 0.0905205 0.2
-1.225 0.0905205 0.2
-1.175 0.122006 0.2
-1.125 0.122006 0.2
-1.075 0.160351 0.2
-1.025 0.160351 0.2
-0.975 0.20552 0.2
-0.925 0.20552 0.2
-0.875 0.2569 0.2
-0.825 0.2569 0.2
-0.775 0.313207 0.2
-0.725 0.313207 0.2
-0.675 0.372462 0.2
-0.625 0.372462 0.2
-0.575 0.432056 0.2
-0.525 0.432056 0.2
-0.475 0.488905 0.2
-0.425 0.488905 0.2
-0.375 0.5397 0.2
-0.325 0.5397 0.2
-0.275 0.581216 0.2
-0.225 0.581216 0.2
-0.175 0.610645 0.2
-0.125 0.610645 0.2
-0.075 0.625911 0.2
-0.025 0.625911 0.2
0.025 0.625911 0.2
0.075 0.625911 0.2
0.125 0.610645 0.2
0.175 0.610645 0.2
0.225 0.581216 0.2
0.275 0.581216 0.2
0.325 0.5397 0.2
0.375 0.5397 0.2
0.425 0.488905 0.2
0.475 0.488905 0.2
0.525 0.432056 0.2
0.575 0.432056 0.2
0.625 0.372462 0.2
0.675 0.372462 0.2
0.725 0.313207 0.2
0.775 0.313207 0.2
0.825 0.2569 0.2
0.875 0.2569 0.2
0.925 0.20552 0.2
0.975 0.20552 0.2
1.025 0.160351 0.2
1.075 0.160351 0.2
1.125 0.122006 0.2
1.175 0.122006 0.2
1.225 0.0905205 0.2
1.275 0.0905205 0.2
1.325 0.0654829 0.2
1.375 0.0654829 0.2
1.425 0.0461827 0.2
1.475 0.0461827 0.2
1.525 0.0317506 0.2
1.575 0.0317506 0.2
1.625 0.0212762 0.2
1.675 0.0212762 0.2
1.725 0.0138946 0.2
1.775 0.0138946 0.2
1.825 0.00884205 0.2
1.875 0.00884205 0.2
1.925 0.00548207 0.2
1.975 0.00548207 0.2
2.025 0.00331095 0.2
2.075 0.00331095 0.2
2.125 0.00194762 0.2
2.175 0.00194762 0.2
2.225 0.00111563 0.2
2.275 0.00111563 0.2
2.325 0.000622176 0.2
2.375 0.000622176 0.2
2.425 0.000337753 0.2
2.475 0.000337753 0.2
2.525 0.000178435 0.2
2.575 0.000178435 0.2
2.625 9.17192e-05 0.2
2.675 9.17192e-05 0.2
2.725 4.58596e-05 0.2
2.775 4.58596e-05 0.2
2.825 2.22987e-05 0.2
2.875 2.22987e-05 0.2
2.925 1.05412e-05 0.2
2.975 1.05412e-05 0.2
3.025 4.84325e-06 0.2
3.075 4.84325e-06 0.2
3.125 2.16217e-06 0.2
3.175 2.16217e-06 0.2
3.225 9.37577e-07 0.2
3.275 9.37577e-07 0.2
3.325 3.94769e-07 0.2
3.375 3.94769e-07 0.2
3.425 1.6134e-07 0.2
3.475 1.6134e-07 0.2
3.525 6.39798e-08 0.2
3.575 6.39798e-08 0.2
3.625 2.46076e-08 0.2
3.675 2.46076e-08 0.2
3.725 9.17573e-09 0.2
3.775 9.17573e-09 0.2
3.825 3.3156e-09 0.2
3.875 3.3156e-09 0.2
3.925 1.16046e-09 0.2
3.975 1.16046e-09 0.2
4.025 3.93214e-10 0.2
4.075 3.93214e-10 0.2
4.125 1.28922e-10 0.2
4.175 1.28922e-10 0.2
4.225 4.08779e-11 0.2
4.275 4.08779e-11 0.2
4.325 1.25271e-11 0.2
4.375 1.25271e-11 0.2
4.425 3.70802e-12 0.2
4.475 3.70802e-12 0.2
4.525 1.05943e-12 0.2
4.575 1.05942e-12 0.2
4.625 2.91958e-13 0.2
4.675 2.91913e-13 0.2
4.725 7.74972e-14 0.2
4.775 7.72919e-14 0.2
4.825 1.95769e-14 0.2
4.875 1.86839e-14 0.2
4.925 3.72792e-15 0.2
4.975 0 0.2


-4.975 6.36108e-10 0.3
-4.925 6.36108e-10 0.3
-4.875 1.13723e-09 0.3
-4.825 1.13723e-09 0.3
-4.775 2.48722e-09 0.3
-4.725 2.48722e-09 0.3
-4.675 5.58972e-09 0.3
-4.625 5.58972e-09 0.3
-4.575 1.24246e-08 0.3
-4.525 1.24246e-08 0.3
-4.475 2.71298e-08 0.3
-4.425 2.71298e-08 0.3
-4.375 5.81322e-08 0.3
-4.325 5.81322e-08 0.3
-4.275 1.22226e-07 0.3
-4.225 1.22226e-07 0.3
-4.175 2.52187e-07 0.3
-4.125 2.52187e-07 0.3
-4.075 5.10678e-07 0.3
-4.025 5.10678e-07 0.3
-3.975 1.01505e-06 0.3
-3.925 1.01505e-06 0.3
-3.875 1.98059e-06 0.3
-3.825 1.98059e-06 0.3
-3.775 3.79414e-06 0.3
-3.725 3.79414e-06 0.3
-3.675 7.13659e-06 0.3
-3.625 7.13659e-06 0.3
-3.575 1.31817e-05 0.3
-3.525 1.31817e-05 0.3
-3.475 2.3911e-05 0.3
-3.425 2.3911e-05 0.3
-3.375 4.26e-05 0.3
-3.325 4.26e-05 0.3
-3.275 7.45501e-05 0.3
-3.225 7.45501e-05 0.3
-3.175 0.000128159 0.3
-3.125 0.000128159 0.3
-3.075 0.000216447 0.3
-3.025 0.000216447 0.3
-2.975 0.000359159 0.3
-2.925 0.000359159 0.3
-2.875 0.000585585 0.3
-2.825 0.000585585 0.3
-2.775 0.000938195 0.3
-2.725 0.000938195 0.3
-2.675 0.00147716 0.3
-2.625 0.00147716 0.3
-2.575 0.00228571 0.3
-2.525 0.00228571 0.3
-2.475 0.00347618 0.3
-2.425 0.00347618 0.3
-2.375 0.00519635 0.3
-2.325 0.00519635 0.3
-2.275 0.00763545 0.3
-2.225 0.00763545 0.3
-2.175 0.011029 0.3
-2.125 0.011029 0.3
-2.075 0.0156612 0.3
-2.025 0.0156612 0.3
-1.975 0.0218636 0.3
-1.925 0.0218636 0.3
-1.875 0.0300089 0.3
-1.825 0.0300089 0.3
-1.775 0.0404974 0.3
-1.725 0.0404974 0.3
-1.675 0.0537369 0.3
-1.625 0.0537369 0.3
-1.575 0.0701139 0.3
-1.525 0.0701139 0.3
-1.475 0.0899575 0.3
-1.425 0.0899575 0.3
-1.375 0.113498 0.3
-1.325 0.113498 0.3
-1.275 0.140821 0.3
-1.225 0.140821 0.3
-1.175 0.171828 0.3
-1.125 0.171828 0.3
-1.075 0.206193 0.3
-1.025 0.206193 0.3
-0.975 0.243345 0.3
-0.925 0.243345 0.3
-0.875 0.282454 0.3
-0.825 0.282454 0.3
-0.775 0.322448 0.3
-0.725 0.322448 0.3
-0.675 0.362047 0.3
-0.625 0.362047 0.3
-0.575 0.399826 0.3
-0.525 0.399826 0.3
-0.475 0.434293 0.3
-0.425 0.434293 0.3
-0.375 0.463989 0.3
-0.325 0.463989 0.3
-0.275 0.487581 0.3
-0.225 0.487581 0.3
-0.175 0.503971 0.3
-0.125 0.503971 0.3
-0.075 0.51237 0.3
-0.025 0.51237 0.3
0.025 0.51237 0.3
0.075 0.51237 0.3
0.125 0.503971 0.3
0.175 0.503971 0.3
0.225 0.487581 0.3
0.275 0.487581 0.3
0.325 0.463989 0.3
0.375 0.463989 0.3
0.425 0.434293 0.3
0.475 0.434293 0.3
0.525 0.399826 0.3
0.575 0.399826 0.3
0.625 0.362047 0.3
0.675 0.362047 0.3
0.725 0.322448 0.3
0.775 0.322448 0.3
0.825 0.282454 0.3
0.875 0.282454 0.3
0.925 0.243345 0.3
0.975 0.243345 0.3
1.025 0.206193 0.3
1.075 0.206193 0.3
1.125 0.171828 0.3
1.175 0.171828 0.3
1.225 0.140821 0.3
1.275 0.140821 0.3
1.325 0.113498 0.3
1.375 0.113498 0.3
1.425 0.0899575 0.3
1.475 0.0899575 0.3
1.525 0.0701139 0.3
1.575 0.0701139 0.3
1.625 0.0537369 0.3
1.675 0.0537369 0.3
1.725 0.0404974 0.3
1.775 0.0404974 0.3
1.825 0.0300089 0.3
1.875 0.0300089 0.3
1.925 0.0218636 0.3
1.975 0.0218636 0.3
2.025 0.0156612 0.3
2.075 0.0156612 0.3
2.125 0.011029 0.3
2.175 0.011029 0.3
2.225 0.00763545 0.3
2.275 0.00763545 0.3
2.325 0.00519635 0.3
2.375 0.00519635 0.3
2.425 0.00347618 0.3
2.475 0.00347618 0.3
2.525 0.00228571 0.3
2.575 0.00228571 0.3
2.625 0.00147716 0.3
2.675 0.00147716 0.3
2.725 0.000938195 0.3
2.775 0.000938195 0.3
2.825 0.000585585 0.3
2.875 0.000585585 0.3
2.925 0.000359159 0.3
2.975 0.000359159 0.3
3.025 0.000216447 0.3
3.075 0.000216447 0.3
3.125 0.000128159 0.3
3.175 0.000128159 0.3
3.225 7.45501e-05 0.3
3.275 7.45501e-05 0.3
3.325 4.26e-05 0.3
3.375 4.26e-05 0.3
3.425 2.3911e-05 0.3
3.475 2.3911e-05 0.3
3.525 1.31817e-05 0.3
3.575 1.31817e-05 0.3
3.625 7.13659e-06 0.3
3.675 7.13659e-06 0.3
3.725 3.79414e-06 0.3
3.775 3.79414e-06 0.3
3.825 1.98059e-06 0.3
3.875 1.98059e-06 0.3
3.925 1.01505e-06 0.3
3.975 1.01505e-06 0.3
4.025 5.10678e-07 0.3
4.075 5.10678e-07 0.3
4.125 2.52186e-07 0.3
4.175 2.52186e-07 0.3
4.225 1.22225e-07 0.3
4.275 1.22225e-07 0.3
4.325 5.8131e-08 0.3
4.375 5.81299e-08 0.3
4.425 2.71264e-08 0.3
4.475 2.71235e-08 0.3
4.525 1.24155e-08 0.3
4.575 1.24082e-08 0.3
4.625 5.56604e-09 0.3
4.675 5.54759e-09 0.3
4.725 2.42663e-09 0.3
4.775 2.38097e-09 0.3
4.825 9.85322e-10 0.3
4.875 8.74648e-10 0.3
4.925 2.62854e-10 0.3
4.975 0 0.3


-4.975 1.30066e-07 0.4
-4.925 1.30066e-07 0.4
-4.875 1.8307e-07 0.4
-4.825 1.8307e-07 0.4
-4.775 3.07474e-07 0.4
-4.725 3.07474e-07 0.4
-4.675 5.45292e-07 0.4
-4.625 5.45292e-07 0.4
-4.575 9.73702e-07 0.4
-4.525 9.73702e-07 0.4
-4.475 1.72532e-06 0.4
-4.425 1.72532e-06 0.4
-4.375 3.02113e-06 0.4
-4.325 3.02113e-06 0.4
-4.275 5.22208e-06 0.4
-4.225 5.22208e-06 0.4
-4.175 8.90784e-06 0.4
-4.125 8.90784e-06 0.4
-4.075 1.49947e-05 0.4
-4.025 1.49947e-05 0.4
-3.975 2.49084e-05 0.4
-3.925 2.49084e-05 0.4
-3.875 4.08334e-05 0.4
-3.825 4.08334e-05 0.4
-3.775 6.60638e-05 0.4
-3.725 6.60638e-05 0.4
-3.675 0.000105489 0.4
-3.625 0.000105489 0.4
-3.575 0.000166251 0.4
-3.525 0.000166251 0.4
-3.475 0.000258612 0.4
-3.425 0.000258612 0.4
-3.375 0.000397082 0.4
-3.325 0.000397082 0.4
-3.275 0.000601827 0.4
-3.225 0.000601827 0.4
-3.175 0.000900407 0.4
-3.125 0.000900407 0.4
-3.075 0.00132983 0.4
-3.025 0.00132983 0.4
-2.975 0.00193892 0.4
-2.925 0.00193892 0.4
-2.875 0.00279086 0.4
-2.825 0.00279086 0.4
-2.775 0.00396596 0.4
-2.725 0.00396596 0.4
-2.675 0.00556419 0.4
-2.625 0.00556419 0.4
-2.575 0.00770743 0.4
-2.525 0.00770743 0.4
-2.475 0.010541 0.4
-2.425 0.010541 0.4
-2.375 0.0142343 0.4
-2.325 0.0142343 0.4
-2.275 0.018979 0.4
-2.225 0.018979 0.4
-2.175 0.0249868 0.4
-2.125 0.0249868 0.4
-2.075 0.0324828 0.4
-2.025 0.0324828 0.4
-1.975 0.0416978 0.4
-1.925 0.0416978 0.4
-1.875 0.0528563 0.4
-1.825 0.0528563 0.4
-1.775 0.0661628 0.4
-1.725 0.0661628 0.4
-1.675 0.0817846 0.4
-1.625 0.0817846 0.4
-1.575 0.0998336 0.4
-1.525 0.0998336 0.4
-1.475 0.120347 0.4
-1.425 0.120347 0.4
-1.375 0.143271 0.4
-1.325 0.143271 0.4
-1.275 0.16844 0.4
-1.225 0.16844 0.4
-1.175 0.195571 0.4
-1.125 0.195571 0.4
-1.075 0.224255 0.4
-1.025 0.224255 0.4
-0.975 0.253957 0.4
-0.925 0.253957 0.4
-0.875 0.284031 0.4
-0.825 0.284031 0.4
-0.775 0.313734 0.4
-0.725 0.313734 0.4
-0.675 0.342255 0.4
-0.625 0.342255 0.4
-0.575 0.368752 0.4
-0.525 0.368752 0.4
-0.475 0.39239 0.4
-0.425 0.39239 0.4
-0.375 0.412385 0.4
-0.325 0.412385 0.4
-0.275 0.428045 0.4
-0.225 0.428045 0.4
-0.175 0.438813 0.4
-0.125 0.438813 0.4
-0.075 0.444299 0.4
-0.025 0.444299 0.4
0.025 0.444299 0.4
0.075 0.444299 0.4
0.125 0.438813 0.4
0.175 0.438813 0.4
0.225 0.428045 0.4
0.275 0.428045 0.4
0.325 0.412385 0.4
0.375 0.412385 0.4
0.425 0.39239 0.4
0.475 0.39239 0.4
0.525 0.368752 0.4
0.575 0.368752 0.4
0.625 0.342255 0.4
0.675 0.342255 0.4
0.725 0.313734 0.4
0.775 0.313734 0.4
0.825 0.284031 0.4
0.875 0.284031 0.4
0.925 0.253957 0.4
0.975 0.253957 0.4
1.025 0.224255 0.4
1.075 0.224255 0.4
1.125 0.195571 0.4
1.175 0.195571 0.4
1.225 0.16844 0.4
1.275 0.16844 0.4
1.325 0.143271 0.4
1.375 0.143271 0.4
1.425 0.120347 0.4
1.475 0.120347 0.4
1.525 0.0998336 0.4
1.575 0.0998336 0.4
1.625 0.0817846 0.4
1.675 0.0817846 0.4
1.725 0.0661628 0.4
1.775 0.0661628 0.4
1.825 0.0528563 0.4
1.875 0.0528563 0.4
1.925 0.0416978 0.4
1.975 0.0416978 0.4
2.025 0.0324828 0.4
2.075 0.0324828 0.4
2.125 0.0249868 0.4
2.175 0.0249868 0.4
2.225 0.018979 0.4
2.275 0.018979 0.4
2.325 0.0142343 0.4
2.375 0.0142343 0.4
2.425 0.010541 0.4
2.475 0.010541 0.4
2.525 0.00770743 0.4
2.575 0.00770743 0.4
2.625 0.00556419 0.4
2.675 0.00556419 0.4
2.725 0.00396596 0.4
2.775 0.00396596 0.4
2.825 0.00279086 0.4
2.875 0.00279086 0.4
2.925 0.00193892 0.4
2.975 0.00193892 0.4
3.025 0.00132983 0.4
3.075 0.00132983 0.4
3.125 0.000900407 0.4
3.175 0.000900407 0.4
3.225 0.000601827 0.4
3.275 0.000601827 0.4
3.325 0.000397082 0.4
3.375 0.000397082 0.4
3.425 0.000258612 0.4
3.475 0.000258612 0.4
3.525 0.000166251 0.4
3.575 0.000166251 0.4
3.625 0.000105489 0.4
3.675 0.000105489 0.4
3.725 6.60638e-05 0.4
3.775 6.60638e-05 0.4
3.825 4.08334e-05 0.4
3.875 4.08334e-05 0.4
3.925 2.49083e-05 0.4
3.975 2.49083e-05 0.4
4.025 1.49945e-05 0.4
4.075 1.49944e-05 0.4
4.125 8.90752e-06 0.4
4.175 8.90734e-06 0.4
4.225 5.22141e-06 0.4
4.275 5.22103e-06 0.4
4.325 3.01971e-06 0.4
4.375 3.01895e-06 0.4
4.425 1.72238e-06 0.4
4.475 1.72086e-06 0.4
4.525 9.67721e-07 0.4
4.575 9.64703e-07 0.4
4.625 5.33276e-07 0.4
4.675 5.27379e-07 0.4
4.725 2.83664e-07 0.4
4.775 2.72305e-07 0.4
4.825 1.36541e-07 0.4
4.875 1.14969e-07 0.4
4.925 4.03931e-08 0.4
4.975 0 0.4


-4.975 2.85513e-06 0.5
-4.925 2.85513e-06 0.5
-4.875 3.5704e-06 0.5
-4.825 3.5704e-06 0.5
-4.775 5.1477e-06 0.5
-4.725 5.1477e-06 0.5
-4.675 7.90344e-06 0.5
-4.625 7.90344e-06 0.5
-4.575 1.23717e-05 0.5
-4.525 1.23717e-05 0.5
-4.475 1.93821e-05 0.5
-4.425 1.93821e-05 0.5
-4.375 3.01742e-05 0.5
-4.325 3.01742e-05 0.5
-4.275 4.65581e-05 0.5
-4.225 4.65581e-05 0.5
-4.175 7.11327e-05 0.5
-4.125 7.11327e-05 0.5
-4.075 0.000107576 0.5
-4.025 0.000107576 0.5
-3.975 0.000161024 0.5
-3.925 0.000161024 0.5
-3.875 0.00023855 0.5
-3.825 0.00023855 0.5
-3.775 0.000349774 0.5
-3.725 0.000349774 0.5
-3.675 0.000507598 0.5
-3.625 0.000507598 0.5
-3.575 0.000729094 0.5
-3.525 0.000729094 0.5
-3.475 0.00103654 0.5
-3.425 0.00103654 0.5
-3.375 0.00145861 0.5
-3.325 0.00145861 0.5
-3.275 0.00203163 0.5
-3.225 0.00203163 0.5
-3.175 0.00280101 0.5
-3.125 0.00280101 0.5
-3.075 0.00382255 0.5
-3.025 0.00382255 0.5
-2.975 0.0051638 0.5
-2.925 0.0051638 0.5
-2.875 0.00690508 0.5
-2.825 0.00690508 0.5
-2.775 0.00914025 0.5
-2.725 0.00914025 0.5
-2.675 0.0119769 0.5
-2.625 0.0119769 0.5
-2.575 0.0155357 0.5
-2.525 0.0155357 0.5
-2.475 0.0199493 0.5
-2.425 0.0199493 0.5
-2.375 0.0253593 0.5
-2.325 0.0253593 0.5
-2.275 0.0319128 0.5
-2.225 0.0319128 0.5
-2.175 0.0397573 0.5
-2.125 0.0397573 0.5
-2.075 0.049034 0.5
-2.025 0.049034 0.5
-1.975 0.0598702 0.5
-1.925 0.0598702 0.5
-1.875 0.0723706 0.5
-1.825 0.0723706 0.5
-1.775 0.0866074 0.5
-1.725 0.0866074 0.5
-1.675 0.102611 0.5
-1.625 0.102611 0.5
-1.575 0.12036 0.5
-1.525 0.12036 0.5
-1.475 0.139773 0.5
-1.425 0.139773 0.5
-1.375 0.160701 0.5
-1.325 0.160701 0.5
-1.275 0.182926 0.5
-1.225 0.182926 0.5
-1.175 0.206155 0.5
-1.125 0.206155 0.5
-1.075 0.230025 0.5
-1.025 0.230025 0.5
-0.975 0.254112 0.5
-0.925 0.254112 0.5
-0.875 0.277935 0.5
-0.825 0.277935 0.5
-0.775 0.300976 0.5
-0.725 0.300976 0.5
-0.675 0.322696 0.5
-0.625 0.322696 0.5
-0.575 0.342554 0.5
-0.525 0.342554 0.5
-0.475 0.360031 0.5
-0.425 0.360031 0.5
-0.375 0.374652 0.5
-0.325 0.374652 0.5
-0.275 0.386005 0.5
-0.225 0.386005 0.5
-0.175 0.393764 0.5
-0.125 0.393764 0.5
-0.075 0.397701 0.5
-0.025 0.397701 0.5
0.025 0.397701 0.5
0.075 0.397701 0.5
0.125 0.393764 0.5
0.175 0.393764 0.5
0.225 0.386005 0.5
0.275 0.386005 0.5
0.325 0.374652 0.5
0.375 0.374652 0.5
0.425 0.360031 0.5
0.475 0.360031 0.5
0.525 0.342554 0.5
0.575 0.342554 0.5
0.625 0.322696 0.5
0.675 0.322696 0.5
0.725 0.300976 0.5
0.775 0.300976 0.5
0.825 0.277935 0.5
0.875 0.277935 0.5
0.925 0.254112 0.5
0.975 0.254112 0.5
1.025 0.230025 0.5
1.075 0.230025 0.5
1.125 0.206155 0.5
1.175 0.206155 0.5
1.225 0.182926 0.5
1.275 0.182926 0.5
1.325 0.160701 0.5
1.375 0.160701 0.5
1.425 0.139773 0.5
1.475 0.139773 0.5
1.525 0.12036 0.5
1.575 0.12036 0.5
1.625 0.102611 0.5
1.675 0.102611 0.5
1.725 0.0866074 0.5
1.775 0.0866074 0.5
1.825 0.0723706 0.5
1.875 0.0723706 0.5
1.925 0.0598702 0.5
1.975 0.0598702 0.5
2.025 0.049034 0.5
2.075 0.049034 0.5
2.125 0.0397573 0.5
2.175 0.0397573 0.5
2.225 0.0319128 0.5
2.275 0.0319128 0.5
2.325 0.0253593 0.5
2.375 0.0253593 0.5
2.425 0.0199493 0.5
2.475 0.0199493 0.5
2.525 0.0155357 0.5
2.575 0.0155357 0.5
2.625 0.0119769 0.5
2.675 0.0119769 0.5
2.725 0.00914025 0.5
2.775 0.00914025 0.5
2.825 0.00690508 0.5
2.875 0.00690508 0.5
2.925 0.0051638 0.5
2.975 0.0051638 0.5
3.025 0.00382255 0.5
3.075 0.00382255 0.5
3.125 0.00280101 0.5
3.175 0.00280101 0.5
3.225 0.00203163 0.5
3.275 0.00203163 0.5
3.325 0.00145861 0.5
3.375 0.00145861 0.5
3.425 0.00103654 0.5
3.475 0.00103654 0.5
3.525 0.000729094 0.5
3.575 0.000729093 0.5
3.625 0.000507597 0.5
3.675 0.000507596 0.5
3.725 0.000349772 0.5
3.775 0.000349771 0.5
3.825 0.000238546 0.5
3.875 0.000238544 0.5
3.925 0.000161016 0.5
3.975 0.000161013 0.5
4.025 0.000107562 0.5
4.075 0.000107557 0.5
4.125 7.11077e-05 0.5
4.175 7.10975e-05 0.5
4.225 4.65128e-05 0.5
4.275 4.64948e-05 0.5
4.325 3.0093e-05 0.5
4.375 3.00616e-05 0.5
4.425 1.92381e-05 0.5
4.475 1.91838e-05 0.5
4.525 1.21192e-05 0.5
4.575 1.20264e-05 0.5
4.625 7.46532e-06 0.5
4.675 7.30843e-06 0.5
4.725 4.3958e-06 0.5
4.775 4.13339e-06 0.5
4.825 2.29368e-06 0.5
4.875 1.85959e-06 0.5
4.925 7.10231e-07 0.5
4.975 0 0.5

# Cartesian 1D, 800 steps, 0.002852 CPU, 0.002849 real, 5.62e+07 points.step/s, 3 var
```

I would like a heat map like imshow with python: x axis = x and y=time and the color gradient is the temperature.

```
set view map
set dgrid3d 100,100,2
set pm3d at b
set grid x y lc "white" front
unset key
unset surface

splot 'out' u 1:3:2
```

if I write "splot 'out'" it works and takes the third column as color gradient and y axis is the temperature but it's not the purpose.
Do I have to use dgrid3d ? pm3d interpolate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for plot `with image`. You need to adjust the `cbrange` to get the best representation.

**Code:**

```
### plot with image
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-4.975 0 0
-4.925 0 0
-4.875 0 0
-4.825 0 0
-4.775 0 0
-4.725 0 0
-4.675 0 0
-4.625 0 0
-4.575 0 0
-4.525 0 0
-4.475 0 0
-4.425 0 0
-4.375 0 0
-4.325 0 0
-4.275 0 0
-4.225 0 0
-4.175 0 0
-4.125 0 0
-4.075 0 0
-4.025 0 0
-3.975 0 0
-3.925 0 0
-3.875 0 0
-3.825 0 0
-3.775 0 0
-3.725 0 0
-3.675 0 0
-3.625 0 0
-3.575 0 0
-3.525 0 0
-3.475 0 0
-3.425 0 0
-3.375 0 0
-3.325 0 0
-3.275 0 0
-3.225 0 0
-3.175 0 0
-3.125 0 0
-3.075 0 0
-3.025 0 0
-2.975 0 0
-2.925 0 0
-2.875 0 0
-2.825 0 0
-2.775 0 0
-2.725 0 0
-2.675 0 0
-2.625 0 0
-2.575 0 0
-2.525 0 0
-2.475 0 0
-2.425 0 0
-2.375 0 0
-2.325 0 0
-2.275 0 0
-2.225 0 0
-2.175 0 0
-2.125 0 0
-2.075 0 0
-2.025 0 0
-1.975 0 0
-1.925 0 0
-1.875 0 0
-1.825 0 0
-1.775 0 0
-1.725 0 0
-1.675 0 0
-1.625 0 0
-1.575 0 0
-1.525 0 0
-1.475 0 0
-1.425 0 0
-1.375 0 0
-1.325 0 0
-1.275 0 0
-1.225 0 0
-1.175 0 0
-1.125 0 0
-1.075 0 0
-1.025 0 0
-0.975 0 0
-0.925 0 0
-0.875 0 0
-0.825 0 0
-0.775 0 0
-0.725 0 0
-0.675 0 0
-0.625 0 0
-0.575 0 0
-0.525 0 0
-0.475 0 0
-0.425 0 0
-0.375 0 0
-0.325 0 0
-0.275 0 0
-0.225 0 0
-0.175 0 0
-0.125 0 0
-0.075 5 0
-0.025 5 0
0.025 5 0
0.075 5 0
0.125 0 0
0.175 0 0
0.225 0 0
0.275 0 0
0.325 0 0
0.375 0 0
0.425 0 0
0.475 0 0
0.525 0 0
0.575 0 0
0.625 0 0
0.675 0 0
0.725 0 0
0.775 0 0
0.825 0 0
0.875 0 0
0.925 0 0
0.975 0 0
1.025 0 0
1.075 0 0
1.125 0 0
1.175 0 0
1.225 0 0
1.275 0 0
1.325 0 0
1.375 0 0
1.425 0 0
1.475 0 0
1.525 0 0
1.575 0 0
1.625 0 0
1.675 0 0
1.725 0 0
1.775 0 0
1.825 0 0
1.875 0 0
1.925 0 0
1.975 0 0
2.025 0 0
2.075 0 0
2.125 0 0
2.175 0 0
2.225 0 0
2.275 0 0
2.325 0 0
2.375 0 0
2.425 0 0
2.475 0 0
2.525 0 0
2.575 0 0
2.625 0 0
2.675 0 0
2.725 0 0
2.775 0 0
2.825 0 0
2.875 0 0
2.925 0 0
2.975 0 0
3.025 0 0
3.075 0 0
3.125 0 0
3.175 0 0
3.225 0 0
3.275 0 0
3.325 0 0
3.375 0 0
3.425 0 0
3.475 0 0
3.525 0 0
3.575 0 0
3.625 0 0
3.675 0 0
3.725 0 0
3.775 0 0
3.825 0 0
3.875 0 0
3.925 0 0
3.975 0 0
4.025 0 0
4.075 0 0
4.125 0 0
4.175 0 0
4.225 0 0
4.275 0 0
4.325 0 0
4.375 0 0
4.425 0 0
4.475 0 0
4.525 0 0
4.575 0 0
4.625 0 0
4.675 0 0
4.725 0 0
4.775 0 0
4.825 0 0
4.875 0 0
4.925 0 0
4.975 0 0


-4.975 0 0.1
-4.925 0 0.1
-4.875 0 0.1
-4.825 0 0.1
-4.775 0 0.1
-4.725 0 0.1
-4.675 0 0.1
-4.625 0 0.1
-4.575 0 0.1
-4.525 0 0.1
-4.475 0 0.1
-4.425 0 0.1
-4.375 0 0.1
-4.325 0 0.1
-4.275 0 0.1
-4.225 0 0.1
-4.175 0 0.1
-4.125 0 0.1
-4.075 4.1359e-24 0.1
-4.025 4.1359e-24 0.1
-3.975 3.35008e-22 0.1
-3.925 3.35008e-22 0.1
-3.875 1.34003e-20 0.1
-3.825 1.34003e-20 0.1
-3.775 3.52875e-19 0.1
-3.725 3.52875e-19 0.1
-3.675 6.88107e-18 0.1
-3.625 6.88107e-18 0.1
-3.575 1.05968e-16 0.1
-3.525 1.05968e-16 0.1
-3.475 1.34227e-15 0.1
-3.425 1.34227e-15 0.1
-3.375 1.43814e-14 0.1
-3.325 1.43814e-14 0.1
-3.275 1.33028e-13 0.1
-3.225 1.33028e-13 0.1
-3.175 1.07901e-12 0.1
-3.125 1.07901e-12 0.1
-3.075 7.76885e-12 0.1
-3.025 7.76885e-12 0.1
-2.975 5.01444e-11 0.1
-2.925 5.01444e-11 0.1
-2.875 2.92509e-10 0.1
-2.825 2.92509e-10 0.1
-2.775 1.55255e-09 0.1
-2.725 1.55255e-09 0.1
-2.675 7.54094e-09 0.1
-2.625 7.54094e-09 0.1
-2.575 3.36829e-08 0.1
-2.525 3.36829e-08 0.1
-2.475 1.38942e-07 0.1
-2.425 1.38942e-07 0.1
-2.375 5.31248e-07 0.1
-2.325 5.31248e-07 0.1
-2.275 1.88888e-06 0.1
-2.225 1.88888e-06 0.1
-2.175 6.26314e-06 0.1
-2.125 6.26314e-06 0.1
-2.075 1.94157e-05 0.1
-2.025 1.94157e-05 0.1
-1.975 5.63981e-05 0.1
-1.925 5.63981e-05 0.1
-1.875 0.000153813 0.1
-1.825 0.000153813 0.1
-1.775 0.000394564 0.1
-1.725 0.000394564 0.1
-1.675 0.000953529 0.1
-1.625 0.000953529 0.1
-1.575 0.00217405 0.1
-1.525 0.00217405 0.1
-1.475 0.00468256 0.1
-1.425 0.00468256 0.1
-1.375 0.00953855 0.1
-1.325 0.00953855 0.1
-1.275 0.0183958 0.1
-1.225 0.0183958 0.1
-1.175 0.0336199 0.1
-1.125 0.0336199 0.1
-1.075 0.0582744 0.1
-1.025 0.0582744 0.1
-0.975 0.0958708 0.1
-0.925 0.0958708 0.1
-0.875 0.149798 0.1
-0.825 0.149798 0.1
-0.775 0.222428 0.1
-0.725 0.222428 0.1
-0.675 0.314015 0.1
-0.625 0.314015 0.1
-0.575 0.421678 0.1
-0.525 0.421678 0.1
-0.475 0.538811 0.1
-0.425 0.538811 0.1
-0.375 0.65531 0.1
-0.325 0.65531 0.1
-0.275 0.75878 0.1
-0.225 0.75878 0.1
-0.175 0.836604 0.1
-0.125 0.836604 0.1
-0.075 0.878434 0.1
-0.025 0.878434 0.1
0.025 0.878434 0.1
0.075 0.878434 0.1
0.125 0.836604 0.1
0.175 0.836604 0.1
0.225 0.75878 0.1
0.275 0.75878 0.1
0.325 0.65531 0.1
0.375 0.65531 0.1
0.425 0.538811 0.1
0.475 0.538811 0.1
0.525 0.421678 0.1
0.575 0.421678 0.1
0.625 0.314015 0.1
0.675 0.314015 0.1
0.725 0.222428 0.1
0.775 0.222428 0.1
0.825 0.149798 0.1
0.875 0.149798 0.1
0.925 0.0958708 0.1
0.975 0.0958708 0.1
1.025 0.0582744 0.1
1.075 0.0582744 0.1
1.125 0.0336199 0.1
1.175 0.0336199 0.1
1.225 0.0183958 0.1
1.275 0.0183958 0.1
1.325 0.00953855 0.1
1.375 0.00953855 0.1
1.425 0.00468256 0.1
1.475 0.00468256 0.1
1.525 0.00217405 0.1
1.575 0.00217405 0.1
1.625 0.000953529 0.1
1.675 0.000953529 0.1
1.725 0.000394564 0.1
1.775 0.000394564 0.1
1.825 0.000153813 0.1
1.875 0.000153813 0.1
1.925 5.63981e-05 0.1
1.975 5.63981e-05 0.1
2.025 1.94157e-05 0.1
2.075 1.94157e-05 0.1
2.125 6.26314e-06 0.1
2.175 6.26314e-06 0.1
2.225 1.88888e-06 0.1
2.275 1.88888e-06 0.1
2.325 5.31248e-07 0.1
2.375 5.31248e-07 0.1
2.425 1.38942e-07 0.1
2.475 1.38942e-07 0.1
2.525 3.36829e-08 0.1
2.575 3.36829e-08 0.1
2.625 7.54094e-09 0.1
2.675 7.54094e-09 0.1
2.725 1.55255e-09 0.1
2.775 1.55255e-09 0.1
2.825 2.92509e-10 0.1
2.875 2.92509e-10 0.1
2.925 5.01444e-11 0.1
2.975 5.01444e-11 0.1
3.025 7.76885e-12 0.1
3.075 7.76885e-12 0.1
3.125 1.07901e-12 0.1
3.175 1.07901e-12 0.1
3.225 1.33028e-13 0.1
3.275 1.33028e-13 0.1
3.325 1.43814e-14 0.1
3.375 1.43814e-14 0.1
3.425 1.34227e-15 0.1
3.475 1.34227e-15 0.1
3.525 1.05968e-16 0.1
3.575 1.05968e-16 0.1
3.625 6.88107e-18 0.1
3.675 6.88107e-18 0.1
3.725 3.52875e-19 0.1
3.775 3.52875e-19 0.1
3.825 1.34003e-20 0.1
3.875 1.34003e-20 0.1
3.925 3.35008e-22 0.1
3.975 3.35008e-22 0.1
4.025 4.1359e-24 0.1
4.075 4.1359e-24 0.1
4.125 0 0.1
4.175 0 0.1
4.225 0 0.1
4.275 0 0.1
4.325 0 0.1
4.375 0 0.1
4.425 0 0.1
4.475 0 0.1
4.525 0 0.1
4.575 0 0.1
4.625 0 0.1
4.675 0 0.1
4.725 0 0.1
4.775 0 0.1
4.825 0 0.1
4.875 0 0.1
4.925 0 0.1
4.975 0 0.1


-4.975 6.03923e-15 0.2
-4.925 6.03923e-15 0.2
-4.875 2.01022e-14 0.2
-4.825 2.01022e-14 0.2
-4.775 7.76118e-14 0.2
-4.725 7.76118e-14 0.2
-4.675 2.91982e-13 0.2
-4.625 2.91982e-13 0.2
-4.575 1.05944e-12 0.2
-4.525 1.05944e-12 0.2
-4.475 3.70802e-12 0.2
-4.425 3.70802e-12 0.2
-4.375 1.25271e-11 0.2
-4.325 1.25271e-11 0.2
-4.275 4.08779e-11 0.2
-4.225 4.08779e-11 0.2
-4.175 1.28922e-10 0.2
-4.125 1.28922e-10 0.2
-4.075 3.93214e-10 0.2
-4.025 3.93214e-10 0.2
-3.975 1.16046e-09 0.2
-3.925 1.16046e-09 0.2
-3.875 3.3156e-09 0.2
-3.825 3.3156e-09 0.2
-3.775 9.17573e-09 0.2
-3.725 9.17573e-09 0.2
-3.675 2.46076e-08 0.2
-3.625 2.46076e-08 0.2
-3.575 6.39798e-08 0.2
-3.525 6.39798e-08 0.2
-3.475 1.6134e-07 0.2
-3.425 1.6134e-07 0.2
-3.375 3.94769e-07 0.2
-3.325 3.94769e-07 0.2
-3.275 9.37577e-07 0.2
-3.225 9.37577e-07 0.2
-3.175 2.16217e-06 0.2
-3.125 2.16217e-06 0.2
-3.075 4.84325e-06 0.2
-3.025 4.84325e-06 0.2
-2.975 1.05412e-05 0.2
-2.925 1.05412e-05 0.2
-2.875 2.22987e-05 0.2
-2.825 2.22987e-05 0.2
-2.775 4.58596e-05 0.2
-2.725 4.58596e-05 0.2
-2.675 9.17192e-05 0.2
-2.625 9.17192e-05 0.2
-2.575 0.000178435 0.2
-2.525 0.000178435 0.2
-2.475 0.000337753 0.2
-2.425 0.000337753 0.2
-2.375 0.000622176 0.2
-2.325 0.000622176 0.2
-2.275 0.00111563 0.2
-2.225 0.00111563 0.2
-2.175 0.00194762 0.2
-2.125 0.00194762 0.2
-2.075 0.00331095 0.2
-2.025 0.00331095 0.2
-1.975 0.00548207 0.2
-1.925 0.00548207 0.2
-1.875 0.00884205 0.2
-1.825 0.00884205 0.2
-1.775 0.0138946 0.2
-1.725 0.0138946 0.2
-1.675 0.0212762 0.2
-1.625 0.0212762 0.2
-1.575 0.0317506 0.2
-1.525 0.0317506 0.2
-1.475 0.0461827 0.2
-1.425 0.0461827 0.2
-1.375 0.0654829 0.2
-1.325 0.0654829 0.2
-1.275 0.0905205 0.2
-1.225 0.0905205 0.2
-1.175 0.122006 0.2
-1.125 0.122006 0.2
-1.075 0.160351 0.2
-1.025 0.160351 0.2
-0.975 0.20552 0.2
-0.925 0.20552 0.2
-0.875 0.2569 0.2
-0.825 0.2569 0.2
-0.775 0.313207 0.2
-0.725 0.313207 0.2
-0.675 0.372462 0.2
-0.625 0.372462 0.2
-0.575 0.432056 0.2
-0.525 0.432056 0.2
-0.475 0.488905 0.2
-0.425 0.488905 0.2
-0.375 0.5397 0.2
-0.325 0.5397 0.2
-0.275 0.581216 0.2
-0.225 0.581216 0.2
-0.175 0.610645 0.2
-0.125 0.610645 0.2
-0.075 0.625911 0.2
-0.025 0.625911 0.2
0.025 0.625911 0.2
0.075 0.625911 0.2
0.125 0.610645 0.2
0.175 0.610645 0.2
0.225 0.581216 0.2
0.275 0.581216 0.2
0.325 0.5397 0.2
0.375 0.5397 0.2
0.425 0.488905 0.2
0.475 0.488905 0.2
0.525 0.432056 0.2
0.575 0.432056 0.2
0.625 0.372462 0.2
0.675 0.372462 0.2
0.725 0.313207 0.2
0.775 0.313207 0.2
0.825 0.2569 0.2
0.875 0.2569 0.2
0.925 0.20552 0.2
0.975 0.20552 0.2
1.025 0.160351 0.2
1.075 0.160351 0.2
1.125 0.122006 0.2
1.175 0.122006 0.2
1.225 0.0905205 0.2
1.275 0.0905205 0.2
1.325 0.0654829 0.2
1.375 0.0654829 0.2
1.425 0.0461827 0.2
1.475 0.0461827 0.2
1.525 0.0317506 0.2
1.575 0.0317506 0.2
1.625 0.0212762 0.2
1.675 0.0212762 0.2
1.725 0.0138946 0.2
1.775 0.0138946 0.2
1.825 0.00884205 0.2
1.875 0.00884205 0.2
1.925 0.00548207 0.2
1.975 0.00548207 0.2
2.025 0.00331095 0.2
2.075 0.00331095 0.2
2.125 0.00194762 0.2
2.175 0.00194762 0.2
2.225 0.00111563 0.2
2.275 0.00111563 0.2
2.325 0.000622176 0.2
2.375 0.000622176 0.2
2.425 0.000337753 0.2
2.475 0.000337753 0.2
2.525 0.000178435 0.2
2.575 0.000178435 0.2
2.625 9.17192e-05 0.2
2.675 9.17192e-05 0.2
2.725 4.58596e-05 0.2
2.775 4.58596e-05 0.2
2.825 2.22987e-05 0.2
2.875 2.22987e-05 0.2
2.925 1.05412e-05 0.2
2.975 1.05412e-05 0.2
3.025 4.84325e-06 0.2
3.075 4.84325e-06 0.2
3.125 2.16217e-06 0.2
3.175 2.16217e-06 0.2
3.225 9.37577e-07 0.2
3.275 9.37577e-07 0.2
3.325 3.94769e-07 0.2
3.375 3.94769e-07 0.2
3.425 1.6134e-07 0.2
3.475 1.6134e-07 0.2
3.525 6.39798e-08 0.2
3.575 6.39798e-08 0.2
3.625 2.46076e-08 0.2
3.675 2.46076e-08 0.2
3.725 9.17573e-09 0.2
3.775 9.17573e-09 0.2
3.825 3.3156e-09 0.2
3.875 3.3156e-09 0.2
3.925 1.16046e-09 0.2
3.975 1.16046e-09 0.2
4.025 3.93214e-10 0.2
4.075 3.93214e-10 0.2
4.125 1.28922e-10 0.2
4.175 1.28922e-10 0.2
4.225 4.08779e-11 0.2
4.275 4.08779e-11 0.2
4.325 1.25271e-11 0.2
4.375 1.25271e-11 0.2
4.425 3.70802e-12 0.2
4.475 3.70802e-12 0.2
4.525 1.05943e-12 0.2
4.575 1.05942e-12 0.2
4.625 2.91958e-13 0.2
4.675 2.91913e-13 0.2
4.725 7.74972e-14 0.2
4.775 7.72919e-14 0.2
4.825 1.95769e-14 0.2
4.875 1.86839e-14 0.2
4.925 3.72792e-15 0.2
4.975 0 0.2


-4.975 6.36108e-10 0.3
-4.925 6.36108e-10 0.3
-4.875 1.13723e-09 0.3
-4.825 1.13723e-09 0.3
-4.775 2.48722e-09 0.3
-4.725 2.48722e-09 0.3
-4.675 5.58972e-09 0.3
-4.625 5.58972e-09 0.3
-4.575 1.24246e-08 0.3
-4.525 1.24246e-08 0.3
-4.475 2.71298e-08 0.3
-4.425 2.71298e-08 0.3
-4.375 5.81322e-08 0.3
-4.325 5.81322e-08 0.3
-4.275 1.22226e-07 0.3
-4.225 1.22226e-07 0.3
-4.175 2.52187e-07 0.3
-4.125 2.52187e-07 0.3
-4.075 5.10678e-07 0.3
-4.025 5.10678e-07 0.3
-3.975 1.01505e-06 0.3
-3.925 1.01505e-06 0.3
-3.875 1.98059e-06 0.3
-3.825 1.98059e-06 0.3
-3.775 3.79414e-06 0.3
-3.725 3.79414e-06 0.3
-3.675 7.13659e-06 0.3
-3.625 7.13659e-06 0.3
-3.575 1.31817e-05 0.3
-3.525 1.31817e-05 0.3
-3.475 2.3911e-05 0.3
-3.425 2.3911e-05 0.3
-3.375 4.26e-05 0.3
-3.325 4.26e-05 0.3
-3.275 7.45501e-05 0.3
-3.225 7.45501e-05 0.3
-3.175 0.000128159 0.3
-3.125 0.000128159 0.3
-3.075 0.000216447 0.3
-3.025 0.000216447 0.3
-2.975 0.000359159 0.3
-2.925 0.000359159 0.3
-2.875 0.000585585 0.3
-2.825 0.000585585 0.3
-2.775 0.000938195 0.3
-2.725 0.000938195 0.3
-2.675 0.00147716 0.3
-2.625 0.00147716 0.3
-2.575 0.00228571 0.3
-2.525 0.00228571 0.3
-2.475 0.00347618 0.3
-2.425 0.00347618 0.3
-2.375 0.00519635 0.3
-2.325 0.00519635 0.3
-2.275 0.00763545 0.3
-2.225 0.00763545 0.3
-2.175 0.011029 0.3
-2.125 0.011029 0.3
-2.075 0.0156612 0.3
-2.025 0.0156612 0.3
-1.975 0.0218636 0.3
-1.925 0.0218636 0.3
-1.875 0.0300089 0.3
-1.825 0.0300089 0.3
-1.775 0.0404974 0.3
-1.725 0.0404974 0.3
-1.675 0.0537369 0.3
-1.625 0.0537369 0.3
-1.575 0.0701139 0.3
-1.525 0.0701139 0.3
-1.475 0.0899575 0.3
-1.425 0.0899575 0.3
-1.375 0.113498 0.3
-1.325 0.113498 0.3
-1.275 0.140821 0.3
-1.225 0.140821 0.3
-1.175 0.171828 0.3
-1.125 0.171828 0.3
-1.075 0.206193 0.3
-1.025 0.206193 0.3
-0.975 0.243345 0.3
-0.925 0.243345 0.3
-0.875 0.282454 0.3
-0.825 0.282454 0.3
-0.775 0.322448 0.3
-0.725 0.322448 0.3
-0.675 0.362047 0.3
-0.625 0.362047 0.3
-0.575 0.399826 0.3
-0.525 0.399826 0.3
-0.475 0.434293 0.3
-0.425 0.434293 0.3
-0.375 0.463989 0.3
-0.325 0.463989 0.3
-0.275 0.487581 0.3
-0.225 0.487581 0.3
-0.175 0.503971 0.3
-0.125 0.503971 0.3
-0.075 0.51237 0.3
-0.025 0.51237 0.3
0.025 0.51237 0.3
0.075 0.51237 0.3
0.125 0.503971 0.3
0.175 0.503971 0.3
0.225 0.487581 0.3
0.275 0.487581 0.3
0.325 0.463989 0.3
0.375 0.463989 0.3
0.425 0.434293 0.3
0.475 0.434293 0.3
0.525 0.399826 0.3
0.575 0.399826 0.3
0.625 0.362047 0.3
0.675 0.362047 0.3
0.725 0.322448 0.3
0.775 0.322448 0.3
0.825 0.282454 0.3
0.875 0.282454 0.3
0.925 0.243345 0.3
0.975 0.243345 0.3
1.025 0.206193 0.3
1.075 0.206193 0.3
1.125 0.171828 0.3
1.175 0.171828 0.3
1.225 0.140821 0.3
1.275 0.140821 0.3
1.325 0.113498 0.3
1.375 0.113498 0.3
1.425 0.0899575 0.3
1.475 0.0899575 0.3
1.525 0.0701139 0.3
1.575 0.0701139 0.3
1.625 0.0537369 0.3
1.675 0.0537369 0.3
1.725 0.0404974 0.3
1.775 0.0404974 0.3
1.825 0.0300089 0.3
1.875 0.0300089 0.3
1.925 0.0218636 0.3
1.975 0.0218636 0.3
2.025 0.0156612 0.3
2.075 0.0156612 0.3
2.125 0.011029 0.3
2.175 0.011029 0.3
2.225 0.00763545 0.3
2.275 0.00763545 0.3
2.325 0.00519635 0.3
2.375 0.00519635 0.3
2.425 0.00347618 0.3
2.475 0.00347618 0.3
2.525 0.00228571 0.3
2.575 0.00228571 0.3
2.625 0.00147716 0.3
2.675 0.00147716 0.3
2.725 0.000938195 0.3
2.775 0.000938195 0.3
2.825 0.000585585 0.3
2.875 0.000585585 0.3
2.925 0.000359159 0.3
2.975 0.000359159 0.3
3.025 0.000216447 0.3
3.075 0.000216447 0.3
3.125 0.000128159 0.3
3.175 0.000128159 0.3
3.225 7.45501e-05 0.3
3.275 7.45501e-05 0.3
3.325 4.26e-05 0.3
3.375 4.26e-05 0.3
3.425 2.3911e-05 0.3
3.475 2.3911e-05 0.3
3.525 1.31817e-05 0.3
3.575 1.31817e-05 0.3
3.625 7.13659e-06 0.3
3.675 7.13659e-06 0.3
3.725 3.79414e-06 0.3
3.775 3.79414e-06 0.3
3.825 1.98059e-06 0.3
3.875 1.98059e-06 0.3
3.925 1.01505e-06 0.3
3.975 1.01505e-06 0.3
4.025 5.10678e-07 0.3
4.075 5.10678e-07 0.3
4.125 2.52186e-07 0.3
4.175 2.52186e-07 0.3
4.225 1.22225e-07 0.3
4.275 1.22225e-07 0.3
4.325 5.8131e-08 0.3
4.375 5.81299e-08 0.3
4.425 2.71264e-08 0.3
4.475 2.71235e-08 0.3
4.525 1.24155e-08 0.3
4.575 1.24082e-08 0.3
4.625 5.56604e-09 0.3
4.675 5.54759e-09 0.3
4.725 2.42663e-09 0.3
4.775 2.38097e-09 0.3
4.825 9.85322e-10 0.3
4.875 8.74648e-10 0.3
4.925 2.62854e-10 0.3
4.975 0 0.3


-4.975 1.30066e-07 0.4
-4.925 1.30066e-07 0.4
-4.875 1.8307e-07 0.4
-4.825 1.8307e-07 0.4
-4.775 3.07474e-07 0.4
-4.725 3.07474e-07 0.4
-4.675 5.45292e-07 0.4
-4.625 5.45292e-07 0.4
-4.575 9.73702e-07 0.4
-4.525 9.73702e-07 0.4
-4.475 1.72532e-06 0.4
-4.425 1.72532e-06 0.4
-4.375 3.02113e-06 0.4
-4.325 3.02113e-06 0.4
-4.275 5.22208e-06 0.4
-4.225 5.22208e-06 0.4
-4.175 8.90784e-06 0.4
-4.125 8.90784e-06 0.4
-4.075 1.49947e-05 0.4
-4.025 1.49947e-05 0.4
-3.975 2.49084e-05 0.4
-3.925 2.49084e-05 0.4
-3.875 4.08334e-05 0.4
-3.825 4.08334e-05 0.4
-3.775 6.60638e-05 0.4
-3.725 6.60638e-05 0.4
-3.675 0.000105489 0.4
-3.625 0.000105489 0.4
-3.575 0.000166251 0.4
-3.525 0.000166251 0.4
-3.475 0.000258612 0.4
-3.425 0.000258612 0.4
-3.375 0.000397082 0.4
-3.325 0.000397082 0.4
-3.275 0.000601827 0.4
-3.225 0.000601827 0.4
-3.175 0.000900407 0.4
-3.125 0.000900407 0.4
-3.075 0.00132983 0.4
-3.025 0.00132983 0.4
-2.975 0.00193892 0.4
-2.925 0.00193892 0.4
-2.875 0.00279086 0.4
-2.825 0.00279086 0.4
-2.775 0.00396596 0.4
-2.725 0.00396596 0.4
-2.675 0.00556419 0.4
-2.625 0.00556419 0.4
-2.575 0.00770743 0.4
-2.525 0.00770743 0.4
-2.475 0.010541 0.4
-2.425 0.010541 0.4
-2.375 0.0142343 0.4
-2.325 0.0142343 0.4
-2.275 0.018979 0.4
-2.225 0.018979 0.4
-2.175 0.0249868 0.4
-2.125 0.0249868 0.4
-2.075 0.0324828 0.4
-2.025 0.0324828 0.4
-1.975 0.0416978 0.4
-1.925 0.0416978 0.4
-1.875 0.0528563 0.4
-1.825 0.0528563 0.4
-1.775 0.0661628 0.4
-1.725 0.0661628 0.4
-1.675 0.0817846 0.4
-1.625 0.0817846 0.4
-1.575 0.0998336 0.4
-1.525 0.0998336 0.4
-1.475 0.120347 0.4
-1.425 0.120347 0.4
-1.375 0.143271 0.4
-1.325 0.143271 0.4
-1.275 0.16844 0.4
-1.225 0.16844 0.4
-1.175 0.195571 0.4
-1.125 0.195571 0.4
-1.075 0.224255 0.4
-1.025 0.224255 0.4
-0.975 0.253957 0.4
-0.925 0.253957 0.4
-0.875 0.284031 0.4
-0.825 0.284031 0.4
-0.775 0.313734 0.4
-0.725 0.313734 0.4
-0.675 0.342255 0.4
-0.625 0.342255 0.4
-0.575 0.368752 0.4
-0.525 0.368752 0.4
-0.475 0.39239 0.4
-0.425 0.39239 0.4
-0.375 0.412385 0.4
-0.325 0.412385 0.4
-0.275 0.428045 0.4
-0.225 0.428045 0.4
-0.175 0.438813 0.4
-0.125 0.438813 0.4
-0.075 0.444299 0.4
-0.025 0.444299 0.4
0.025 0.444299 0.4
0.075 0.444299 0.4
0.125 0.438813 0.4
0.175 0.438813 0.4
0.225 0.428045 0.4
0.275 0.428045 0.4
0.325 0.412385 0.4
0.375 0.412385 0.4
0.425 0.39239 0.4
0.475 0.39239 0.4
0.525 0.368752 0.4
0.575 0.368752 0.4
0.625 0.342255 0.4
0.675 0.342255 0.4
0.725 0.313734 0.4
0.775 0.313734 0.4
0.825 0.284031 0.4
0.875 0.284031 0.4
0.925 0.253957 0.4
0.975 0.253957 0.4
1.025 0.224255 0.4
1.075 0.224255 0.4
1.125 0.195571 0.4
1.175 0.195571 0.4
1.225 0.16844 0.4
1.275 0.16844 0.4
1.325 0.143271 0.4
1.375 0.143271 0.4
1.425 0.120347 0.4
1.475 0.120347 0.4
1.525 0.0998336 0.4
1.575 0.0998336 0.4
1.625 0.0817846 0.4
1.675 0.0817846 0.4
1.725 0.0661628 0.4
1.775 0.0661628 0.4
1.825 0.0528563 0.4
1.875 0.0528563 0.4
1.925 0.0416978 0.4
1.975 0.0416978 0.4
2.025 0.0324828 0.4
2.075 0.0324828 0.4
2.125 0.0249868 0.4
2.175 0.0249868 0.4
2.225 0.018979 0.4
2.275 0.018979 0.4
2.325 0.0142343 0.4
2.375 0.0142343 0.4
2.425 0.010541 0.4
2.475 0.010541 0.4
2.525 0.00770743 0.4
2.575 0.00770743 0.4
2.625 0.00556419 0.4
2.675 0.00556419 0.4
2.725 0.00396596 0.4
2.775 0.00396596 0.4
2.825 0.00279086 0.4
2.875 0.00279086 0.4
2.925 0.00193892 0.4
2.975 0.00193892 0.4
3.025 0.00132983 0.4
3.075 0.00132983 0.4
3.125 0.000900407 0.4
3.175 0.000900407 0.4
3.225 0.000601827 0.4
3.275 0.000601827 0.4
3.325 0.000397082 0.4
3.375 0.000397082 0.4
3.425 0.000258612 0.4
3.475 0.000258612 0.4
3.525 0.000166251 0.4
3.575 0.000166251 0.4
3.625 0.000105489 0.4
3.675 0.000105489 0.4
3.725 6.60638e-05 0.4
3.775 6.60638e-05 0.4
3.825 4.08334e-05 0.4
3.875 4.08334e-05 0.4
3.925 2.49083e-05 0.4
3.975 2.49083e-05 0.4
4.025 1.49945e-05 0.4
4.075 1.49944e-05 0.4
4.125 8.90752e-06 0.4
4.175 8.90734e-06 0.4
4.225 5.22141e-06 0.4
4.275 5.22103e-06 0.4
4.325 3.01971e-06 0.4
4.375 3.01895e-06 0.4
4.425 1.72238e-06 0.4
4.475 1.72086e-06 0.4
4.525 9.67721e-07 0.4
4.575 9.64703e-07 0.4
4.625 5.33276e-07 0.4
4.675 5.27379e-07 0.4
4.725 2.83664e-07 0.4
4.775 2.72305e-07 0.4
4.825 1.36541e-07 0.4
4.875 1.14969e-07 0.4
4.925 4.03931e-08 0.4
4.975 0 0.4


-4.975 2.85513e-06 0.5
-4.925 2.85513e-06 0.5
-4.875 3.5704e-06 0.5
-4.825 3.5704e-06 0.5
-4.775 5.1477e-06 0.5
-4.725 5.1477e-06 0.5
-4.675 7.90344e-06 0.5
-4.625 7.90344e-06 0.5
-4.575 1.23717e-05 0.5
-4.525 1.23717e-05 0.5
-4.475 1.93821e-05 0.5
-4.425 1.93821e-05 0.5
-4.375 3.01742e-05 0.5
-4.325 3.01742e-05 0.5
-4.275 4.65581e-05 0.5
-4.225 4.65581e-05 0.5
-4.175 7.11327e-05 0.5
-4.125 7.11327e-05 0.5
-4.075 0.000107576 0.5
-4.025 0.000107576 0.5
-3.975 0.000161024 0.5
-3.925 0.000161024 0.5
-3.875 0.00023855 0.5
-3.825 0.00023855 0.5
-3.775 0.000349774 0.5
-3.725 0.000349774 0.5
-3.675 0.000507598 0.5
-3.625 0.000507598 0.5
-3.575 0.000729094 0.5
-3.525 0.000729094 0.5
-3.475 0.00103654 0.5
-3.425 0.00103654 0.5
-3.375 0.00145861 0.5
-3.325 0.00145861 0.5
-3.275 0.00203163 0.5
-3.225 0.00203163 0.5
-3.175 0.00280101 0.5
-3.125 0.00280101 0.5
-3.075 0.00382255 0.5
-3.025 0.00382255 0.5
-2.975 0.0051638 0.5
-2.925 0.0051638 0.5
-2.875 0.00690508 0.5
-2.825 0.00690508 0.5
-2.775 0.00914025 0.5
-2.725 0.00914025 0.5
-2.675 0.0119769 0.5
-2.625 0.0119769 0.5
-2.575 0.0155357 0.5
-2.525 0.0155357 0.5
-2.475 0.0199493 0.5
-2.425 0.0199493 0.5
-2.375 0.0253593 0.5
-2.325 0.0253593 0.5
-2.275 0.0319128 0.5
-2.225 0.0319128 0.5
-2.175 0.0397573 0.5
-2.125 0.0397573 0.5
-2.075 0.049034 0.5
-2.025 0.049034 0.5
-1.975 0.0598702 0.5
-1.925 0.0598702 0.5
-1.875 0.0723706 0.5
-1.825 0.0723706 0.5
-1.775 0.0866074 0.5
-1.725 0.0866074 0.5
-1.675 0.102611 0.5
-1.625 0.102611 0.5
-1.575 0.12036 0.5
-1.525 0.12036 0.5
-1.475 0.139773 0.5
-1.425 0.139773 0.5
-1.375 0.160701 0.5
-1.325 0.160701 0.5
-1.275 0.182926 0.5
-1.225 0.182926 0.5
-1.175 0.206155 0.5
-1.125 0.206155 0.5
-1.075 0.230025 0.5
-1.025 0.230025 0.5
-0.975 0.254112 0.5
-0.925 0.254112 0.5
-0.875 0.277935 0.5
-0.825 0.277935 0.5
-0.775 0.300976 0.5
-0.725 0.300976 0.5
-0.675 0.322696 0.5
-0.625 0.322696 0.5
-0.575 0.342554 0.5
-0.525 0.342554 0.5
-0.475 0.360031 0.5
-0.425 0.360031 0.5
-0.375 0.374652 0.5
-0.325 0.374652 0.5
-0.275 0.386005 0.5
-0.225 0.386005 0.5
-0.175 0.393764 0.5
-0.125 0.393764 0.5
-0.075 0.397701 0.5
-0.025 0.397701 0.5
0.025 0.397701 0.5
0.075 0.397701 0.5
0.125 0.393764 0.5
0.175 0.393764 0.5
0.225 0.386005 0.5
0.275 0.386005 0.5
0.325 0.374652 0.5
0.375 0.374652 0.5
0.425 0.360031 0.5
0.475 0.360031 0.5
0.525 0.342554 0.5
0.575 0.342554 0.5
0.625 0.322696 0.5
0.675 0.322696 0.5
0.725 0.300976 0.5
0.775 0.300976 0.5
0.825 0.277935 0.5
0.875 0.277935 0.5
0.925 0.254112 0.5
0.975 0.254112 0.5
1.025 0.230025 0.5
1.075 0.230025 0.5
1.125 0.206155 0.5
1.175 0.206155 0.5
1.225 0.182926 0.5
1.275 0.182926 0.5
1.325 0.160701 0.5
1.375 0.160701 0.5
1.425 0.139773 0.5
1.475 0.139773 0.5
1.525 0.12036 0.5
1.575 0.12036 0.5
1.625 0.102611 0.5
1.675 0.102611 0.5
1.725 0.0866074 0.5
1.775 0.0866074 0.5
1.825 0.0723706 0.5
1.875 0.0723706 0.5
1.925 0.0598702 0.5
1.975 0.0598702 0.5
2.025 0.049034 0.5
2.075 0.049034 0.5
2.125 0.0397573 0.5
2.175 0.0397573 0.5
2.225 0.0319128 0.5
2.275 0.0319128 0.5
2.325 0.0253593 0.5
2.375 0.0253593 0.5
2.425 0.0199493 0.5
2.475 0.0199493 0.5
2.525 0.0155357 0.5
2.575 0.0155357 0.5
2.625 0.0119769 0.5
2.675 0.0119769 0.5
2.725 0.00914025 0.5
2.775 0.00914025 0.5
2.825 0.00690508 0.5
2.875 0.00690508 0.5
2.925 0.0051638 0.5
2.975 0.0051638 0.5
3.025 0.00382255 0.5
3.075 0.00382255 0.5
3.125 0.00280101 0.5
3.175 0.00280101 0.5
3.225 0.00203163 0.5
3.275 0.00203163 0.5
3.325 0.00145861 0.5
3.375 0.00145861 0.5
3.425 0.00103654 0.5
3.475 0.00103654 0.5
3.525 0.000729094 0.5
3.575 0.000729093 0.5
3.625 0.000507597 0.5
3.675 0.000507596 0.5
3.725 0.000349772 0.5
3.775 0.000349771 0.5
3.825 0.000238546 0.5
3.875 0.000238544 0.5
3.925 0.000161016 0.5
3.975 0.000161013 0.5
4.025 0.000107562 0.5
4.075 0.000107557 0.5
4.125 7.11077e-05 0.5
4.175 7.10975e-05 0.5
4.225 4.65128e-05 0.5
4.275 4.64948e-05 0.5
4.325 3.0093e-05 0.5
4.375 3.00616e-05 0.5
4.425 1.92381e-05 0.5
4.475 1.91838e-05 0.5
4.525 1.21192e-05 0.5
4.575 1.20264e-05 0.5
4.625 7.46532e-06 0.5
4.675 7.30843e-06 0.5
4.725 4.3958e-06 0.5
4.775 4.13339e-06 0.5
4.825 2.29368e-06 0.5
4.875 1.85959e-06 0.5
4.925 7.10231e-07 0.5
4.975 0 0.5
EOD

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "Time"
set cbrange [0:1]
set cblabel "Temperature"
plot $Data u 1:3:2 w image notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]